# Is there a word for a middle-aged person who tries too hard to keep up with trends?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Is there a word for when someone (often a middle-aged father) constantly tries too hard to keep up with 'trends'?

Comment: Ummm... I suppose *wannabe trendy* wouldn't do, since a *wannabe* normally has overtones of misplaced youthful optimism rather than regression to a second childhood.

Comment: "Let me explain something to you. Um, I am not 'Mr. Lebowski'. You're Mr. Lebowski. I'm the Dude. So that's what you call me. You know, that or, uh, His Dudeness, or uh, Duder, or El Duderino if you're not into the whole brevity thing."

Comment: @Fumble: Well, I stole "wannabe" and added to my answer anyway. Hope you don't mind. :P

Comment: "Wannabe" could refer to anybody who aspires to something they are too lazy/untalented to achieve, though.

Comment: Anyway, I have teenage children myself, and I admit I make a bit of an effort in that direction. Out of paternal interest cum sociability, I like to think, rather than just playing out some neurotic fantasy. Perhaps I should ask *them* if they have a word for it - and if so, is it complimentary or pejorative?

Answer (score 3):

An Ed Hardy customer. :)

In all seriousness though, I like 'painfully hip' for this one. As in 'The painfully hip dad couldn't resist wearing his Ed Hardy shirt to the PTA meeting'. Also, along those same lines, you can say 'tragically hip.'

Answer (score 1):

Other than taking any typical adjective for trendy and negating it (uncool, unhip, untrendy) you can try one of the following:

- desperate
- square
- old-fashioned
- behind the times
- antique / antiquated
- ancient
- dated
- wannabe

Comment: Now I come to think of it, all your 'synonyms' are uncomplimentary. So perhaps you should add *cool*, which has been around for decades in this sense. "Yeah guys, we can smoke a joint at my house. My Dad's *cool*".

Comment: @Fumble: I was under the impression that this is exactly what was requested?

Comment: cover all bases, MrHen!

Answer (score 1):

I like *poser*

From the [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poser) of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions:

> Someone who pretends to belong to a group only by affecting the attributes of the group. (See also mod poser.) :  *What's he doing here? He's just a poser, looking for dates*.

However, it doesn't specify the age of the person.

Comment: It's not actually a slang term - it's a corruption of the French _[poseur](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poseur)_.

Comment: I'm going to stick to my guns on this one, French corruption or not. I found an entry that backs my thinking (see above).  It exists as a standard term, but in the way that I'm using it is slang or informal.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a specific word for the thing you describe, but these might do for you.

The term "mutton dressed as lamb" fits, though this isn't a single word as requested (note that "dressed" refers to food dressing, not clothing) and is usually feminine-specific.

"Middle-aged hipster" fits too, but again is a little specific to the type of thing it describes.